# Cancel iCloud subscription via browser on Windows?

Tags: icloud

I recently switched back from OSX to Windows on my Notebook and from iOS to Android on my phone. I backed up all my files from iCloud via the app for Windows (which I uninstalled after) and would now like to cancel the iCloud storage service. I can't find a way to to do it via the browser. Do I really have to reinstall the iCloud app for Windows in order to do it?

Comment: Is this an additional paid subscription, or the standard 5GB? If it's the regular 5, I'd be tempted to leave it, just in case you ever come back. There's no way to delete an iCloud account, so unless you're paying for it you may as well leave it fallow.

Comment: It's paid 50GB.

Comment: Then I *think* you'll need to do it through the iCloud control panel - for security reasons.

Comment: The iCloud control panel where? In the browser, in the Windows app or the iOS/OSX app?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to install iCloud for Windows. Why you might ask... Because of Apple...

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204283

*Note: Be warned - it is a horrible user experience to try and downgrade your storage to the free plan and remove the credit cart, however it it possible.*

[image]

[image]

Comment: At least it's not iTunes.